# Авторизация в Twitter через requests python

Tags: python, requests

Как произвести авторизацию в Twitter через request. Я пробовал так:

```
import requests

HEADERS = 'здесь user-agent'

url = 'https://twitter.com/login'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url, headers = {
    'User-Agent': HEADERS
})

post_requests = session.post(url, {
     'backUrl': 'https://twitter.com/explore',
     'username': 'login',
     'password': 'password' 
})
```

при выводе:

```
print(post_requests)
```

получаю:

```
<Response [403]>
```

Помогите.

Comment: Твитер жостко банит. Делал подобное, автоматизировал некоторые процессы (даже выгрузку фото, пост, офомрление). Буквально за 2 часа прилетел страйк при том что оттормаживался длительными таймерами (не буянил). Не знаю есть ли смысл тратить время

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы посмотрим на запрос, который отправляется в твитер, при поптыке регистрации, то он отпраляется на адрес https://twitter.com/sessions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а не на https://twitter.com/login, соответственно вместо вашего url укажите другой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После того как получил ответ <Response [200]> можно перейти по другим вкладкам?

Comment: `s = requests.get('https://twitter.com/elonmusk/followers', headers = HEADERS)
soup = BS(s.content.decode("UTF-8"), "html.parser")
title = soup.find("span", class_ = 'css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0').text
print(title)` выдает ошибку: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'